# Structure of atom

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Consider one He+ ion in exited state(n=5).In the answer it is given that no. of spectral lines produced is 4 not 10.can't we use the general equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the question is worded. There are 4 possible lines directly from the n=5  (5-4, 5-3, 5-2, 5-1). There are 10 possible lines if you include all lines from n=4 (4-3, 4-2, 4-1), n=3 (3-2, 3-1), and n=2 (2-1) as well.

Comment: In the solution it's given that multitude of He+ will produce 10 possible lines and single He+ produce max. 4 lines.is it because of the fact that an electron at a time in an atom can occupy only one exited state.